Showing that a generator exponentiates to a $\mathbb{R}$ group
I have a generator $G$ that acts on the phase space of Schwarzschild and maps geodesics into each other.
In order to discuss the corresponding symmetry group, I need to exponentiate this generator and show that it is given by $\mathbb{R}$. However, I am having some trouble doing this, as there is only one generator and I can't rely on any results with the bracket structure.

I don't really understand what you're looking for here in an answer. I assume that by "show it is given by $\mathbb{R}$" you mean that the one-parameter group generated by this generator is $\mathbb{R}$ and not $\mathrm{U}(1)$. In most cases this is obvious (as with rotation generators that yield the identity operator at $2\pi$, hence have U(1) not R). But you have given no details on what this generator is or what problem you have in determining this, so how is anyone supposed to write an answer that's actually helpful to you?

Apologies, it seems I hadn't updated my post. What you are saying is correct though: I'm looking to show that we have a group $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $U(1)$. My question is more related to how to do this theoretically than actually providing the full computation. For example, I have shown that acting with $G$ on some phase space function $f$ goes from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. Would this be enough?

Moreover, how would I write the corresponding Lie algebra of $\mathbb{R}$? do I simply also call it $\mathfrak{u}(1)$?

You have to look at the one-parameter group generated by this and see if for any value of the parameter, the action becomes the identity (like the $U(2\pi) = 1$ for rotations in my example) - then you have a U(1), otherwise not. I consider this more-or-less the definition of the difference between R and U(1), and I don't think that there is anything more to say in general, which is why I'm not really sure what the question is looking for

This then again ties in to my other question: How do I show that the group action is not the identity for all values of the parameter (except $0$)? Can I show this simply from calculating the bracket ${f, G}$ and plotting it over the phase space?

What about the bounty?

From now on, $\{\cdot,\cdot\}$ denotes the Lie commutator of smooth vector fields on a smooth manifold.
As far as I understand, you have a vector field $X$ on $TM$, where $M$ is the Schwarzschild manifold, such that  $\{X, \Gamma\}=0$, where $\Gamma$ is the vector field in $TM$ whose integral lines are the geodesics of $M$ lifted to curves in $TM$.
The condition $\{X, \Gamma\}=0$ is the geometric corresponding of the statement that the action of $X$  maps geodesics into geodesics.
You would like to conclude that the flow of $X$ is complete. Namely, the parameter $t$ of the flow $\Phi^{(X)}_t(p) =: (\exp tX)(p)$ ranges  in the whole $\mathbb{R} = (-\infty, +\infty)$ for every given $p\in M$.
In this sense, $\mathbb{R} \ni t \mapsto \Phi^{(X)}_t \in \text{Diff}(TM)$ is a group representation of the additive group $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ in terms of diffeomorphisms of $TM$ as wanted.
The claim is generally false without further hypotheses on $X$. In fact, just take $X=\Gamma$. Obviously $\{X, \Gamma\}= \{X,X\}=0$.
However, there are maximal geodesics (maximal integral lines of $\Gamma$ and thus $X$) on the Schwarzschild manifold, which are not complete either if the manifold is the Kruskal one or if you consider a Schwarzshild wedge in the former.
In the former case, it is sufficient to consider a timelike geodesic which meets the curvature singularity. In the latter, a geodesic which crosses the Killing horizon is incomplete as well. In both cases, the affine parameter along the said geodesic -- which coincides with the parameter $t$ of the flow -- is defined in a bounded (from above or from below) maximal interval.
(I used the Lie-parenthesis approach, but everything can be equivalently restated in terms of Hamiltonian fields, Poisson parenthesis and one-parameter groups of canonical transformations,  using the natural symplectic structure of $T^*M$. The geodesics lifted to $T^*M$ define the Hamiltonian flow of the Hamiltonian constructed out of the Lagrangian $\frac{1}{2}g(x)(\dot{x}, \dot{x})$ in $TM$.)
